# How to use semctl to set value of nth semaphore in the semaphore set

Tags: c, semaphore

I have created a `System V` semaphore using `semget`

```
#define SEM_ID 250
...
sem_set_id = semget(SEM_ID, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0660);
if (sem_set_id == -1) {
perror("main: semget");
exit(1);
```

now as per my understanding this creates a semaphore set which has many semaphores in it.
But how to identify a particular semaphore to set its value using `semctl`...

```
int iter=0;
for(iter=0;iter<no_of_jobs;iter++)
{
    int rc=semctl(semid,iter,SETVAL, sem_val);
    if(rc==-1)
        {printf("Error:semctl\n");
        exit(1);
        }
}
```

The above code runs for `iter=0` but fails for other. In `struct semun sem_val` I have set the value `sem_val.val=1`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to [`semget()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/semget.html) is the number of semaphores in the semaphore set.  You specified `1`, so you got one semaphore.  Accessing anything other than the one semaphore is going to lead to errors.

Change the `1` to `10`, say, and you should be OK to iterate over semaphores 0..9 inclusive.

Comment: OK; what error does it give?  Maybe your system isn't configured to allow larger semaphore sets.  Start with 2 and see how far it goes. The ways in which kernels are configured vary from system to system; the details of what and how are very, very variable.  At minimum, you'll need to say which O/S you're working with (the answers for Solaris, Mac OS X and Linux are quite different, for example).

Comment: On Mac OS X, some of the relevant parameters are: `kern.sysv.semume=10`, 
`kern.sysv.semmsl=87381`,
`kern.sysv.semmnu=87381`,
`kern.sysv.semmns=87381`,
`kern.sysv.semmni=87381` — and the command to fettle them is `sysctl`.

Comment: It seems as there is some problem with key .... i changed the first parameter value of semget and it worked successfully, is it that when i executed program for first time the semaphore was created and it does not get destroyed when program exits..?? How can i check for existing semaphores in system and remove it?

Comment: `ipcs` and `ipcrm` are the commands (IPC status, and IPC remove).  Doing it programmatically: look at the options to `semget()` et al — and `semctl()`.  Omitting `IPC_CREAT` would attempt to use an existing semaphore set — if that fails, try again with `IPC_CREAT`, but if it succeeds, then remove it with `semctl()` before trying again with `IPC_CREAT`.  If the semaphore set already exists, the size of the set doesn't change, of course.  Semaphore sets are independent of the process that created it, so a semaphore set continues to exist after the process exits, unless you use IPC_PRIVATE.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... :) @Jonathan Leffler